# DolphinDB: why column names of a matrix are renamed

Tags: matrix, dolphindb

I have a table tb. After executing corrMatrix(matrix(tb)) in DolphinDB, all the column names are replaced with serial numbers. I'd like to know why it happens and if there is any way to rename them with the original column names.

Comment: DolphinDB is not MySQL. Which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, the output matrix will share the same column names as the original matrix.
[image]

But the output will be like this if no column name is contained in the original matrix.

[image]

After you convert a table to a matrix, the column names of the original table will be lost. So I suggest you add the column names to the matrix manually.
For example:

```
t=table(1 2 3 as id, 4 5 6 as vol, 7 8 9 as qty)
m=matrix(t).rename!(`id`vol`qty)
corrMatrix(m)
```

[image]